# Call methods by defined names & add extra parameter before being called

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I have a Validator class that can build several arrays with methods (names) stored.

Like so `$this->rules[1] = ['trim()', 'required()', 'max(35)']`;

- How can I loop through every method the array and call it exactly by how they are defined?

If I do it like the following, I get `Undefined property: Validator::$trim()` etc. error.

```
foreach ($this->rules[1] as $method) {
    $this->$method;
}
```

- How can I add an **extra** parameter `$input` to each method in the array **before** it gets in the loop?

So instead of `trim()` it would be `trim($input)`, and for `max(35)` `max(35, $input)`, etc.

Comment: Is the rules construct your idea? Could you maybe alter it?

Comment: Alter it? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I don't think $this->$whatever will ever work, $ after arrow operator seems wrong to me...

Comment: What might be helpfull for you is "call_user_func_array()" have a look   http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array. You could also create your custom validation functions and call em wth arguments this way.

Comment: @sebastian Using a variable after the arrow operator is completely fine. Just not when calling [variable methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) without parenthesis after the var.

Comment: @502 Error: Ah ok, yes makes perfect sense like this ;) Really never had to use it though...but who knows...I can think of situations where you need 100% generic code, so it actually would make a solution more elegant ;) Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use `$this->{$method}` to call your method in your example.

Secondly, don't call them like that at all. Use `call_user_func_array` instead.

You need to extract method name and parameters frist in order to call directly.
I recommend you use a placeholder for your $input to add it to your method call.
You can then pass the parameters for your function call as an array.

```
$ruleset = 'max(34,:input)';
// do the string manipulation yourself please ;-)
$method = 'max';
$input = getInput(); // wherever you get that from
$parameters = array (34, $input),
call_user_func_array(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Validator::' . $method, $parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are the [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func) and/or [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) methods.

As Andresch pointed out, the way your rules are defined aren't flexible. Now you would have to parse them to retrieve the inputs for the function. a better way would be the following format:

```
$this->rules[1] = array(
  'trim',
  'required',
  array('max'=>35)
);
```

and then

```
foreach ( $this->rules as $rule )
{
  if ( is_array($rule) 
  {
    call_user_func_array(array($this, key($rule)), current($rule));
  }
  else
  {
    call_user_func(array($this,$rule));
  }
}
```

P.S. don't just copy paste this code, this is intended for explanation